# How do I send multiple keystroke in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I'm trying to send keystroke in a ruby automation, I don't know how to put this in my code, I want to send (Alt+Space + X) to maximize my window.

Anyone could help me in this one?

```
When("que eu realize login no SIAF com usuário e senha") do |table|
    wsh.SendKeys("%{VK 32}{VK 88}") 
    @usuario = table.rows_hash['usuario']
    @senha = table.rows_hash['senha']


    login.load
    login.log(@usuario,@senha)
  end
```

I expect window to be maximized by command Alt+Space+X, but nothing happens.

My "env.rb" I´m using like this:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/rspec/matchers'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'site_prism'
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'page_helper.rb'


World(Capybara::DSL)
World(Capybara::RSpecMatchers)
World(Pages)

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    mange.window.maximize
    desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
        'chromeOptions' => {'args' => ['--disable-infobars', 
                                        'window-size=1600,1024'] }

    )


)


end
```

Where can I put "Drive.mangage.window.maximize" ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. 
 Check out the documentation for [`send_keys`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#send_keys-instance_method).  You should be able to do something like `element.send_keys :alt, :space, "X"`.  Or just use [Window::maximize](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Window.html#maximize-instance_method).  Good luck!

Comment: There is a standard code to maximize the window why do you have to go via pressing keys

Comment: Hi Marquiiz! Your question is a bit confusing because you mix up the Windows Scripting Host question with the selenium-webdriver. Which one do you want? For the WSH part, please observe that you are actually using ALT+SPACE and then press x to maximize. So just call send_keys twice.

Comment: @Marquiiiz Also a hint about your code samples: It is better to translate everything into English so everyone can understand.

Comment: What I do want is to open my window maximized, thats all , anyway you want, I had pass my env.rb, because I couldnt find a way to use his answer on my code

Comment: If anyone could share a piece of code that does opens my chrome maxmized in ruby automation that works I'would appriciate that

Answer (score 1):

Keys you send are sent to the browser, not the OS, so aren't guaranteed to trigger system actions.  To maximize the window your best best is

```
page.current_window.maximize
```

Comment: hi, can you explain me how both differs? for an example, `driver.find_element.click` trigger the OS but `driver.action.click(driver.find_element).perform` performs the browser level click? what's the difference? both are calling the click module,eh?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Both of those would trigger browser level events. There is no way through webdriver that guarantees OS levels responses

Comment: No,you said there is a difference for triggering the OS level, what is this? How does this differ from triggering the action from browser level?

Comment: @Rajagopalan I don't understand what you're asking? The keystrokes sent are directly sent to the browser via the webdriver protocol.  They don't get routed and handled by the OS like keystrokes directly on a keyboard would (active window, OS keystroke shortcuts, etc)